# How to show tabular structure with editable fields in android Layouts design?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need help for design idea for table structure in android GUI design

[image]

In above table structure 4 th column is editable field and on click of submit button the total details will transferred to parent activity using list array object. List will be dynamic (as its search result).Table structure will be scrollable too

so which design layout is preferable ?

Can we implement Custom list view with editable field or Table layout is good for this requirement I am confused please help me .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you do a table layout for this setup.

Comment: @AndrewQ thank you but require more opinions